# Can we build and deploy worklight application as .ear instead of .war?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, worklight-runtime

Can we build and deploy worklight application as .ear ?
If yes, where do I find the procedure for it.

Answer (score 0):

Both Worklight Studio and Worklight CLI generate .war files, which contain the specific project's metadata required to run the application(s) developed for that project.

An .ear file is a collection of .war files, so while Worklight **will not** generate .ear files for you, you could find an alternate way to create an .ear file and deploy it. It should work. If not, work with the recommended way, which is to use the .war file Worklight generates.

Comment: is it possible to deploy .war file with other application files like .wlapp, .wladapter as single .ear file?

Comment: Worklight documentation does not offer this option, so officially from Worklight - no. However if the documentation of the application server that you're using (was, was liberty, ...) documents this, you can try their suggestions.

Comment: Worklight docs mention using an ant file to do the deployment of the various server artifacts.